# DELETE requests is not answered by nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made this api with some simple PUT and DELETE methods :

```
Data.findOneAndDelete({categories: req.body.categories}, function(err,data){
 if (err) res.send(err)
  res.send(data)
```

They both use mongoose methods for handling the data , however when i make my curl request as following:

```
curl   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -X DELETE   -d '{"categories": { "name" :2, "url_name": "example" }}'   http://localhost:4200/delete
```

The server sends either no response or sends a response for correctly deleting data , but i check the database and the data is still there. I would like to know if the method im using is written incorrectly

The server response is the following :

```
DELETE /delete 200 61.990 ms - 0
```

But it doesnt actually delete the prefered document

Comment: can you update your router delete api

Comment: You could try exec.   Data.findOneAndDelete({categories: req.body.categories}).exec(function (err, data) {  if (err) res.send(err) res.send(data) })

Comment: it returns .exec is not a function

Comment: it still send and OK 200 response but the actual document is not removed from mongodb